# Read Hive table and transform it to Parquet Table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, parquet

The data is from a Hive table, to be more precise

The first table has the properties

```
Serde Library   org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe  
InputFormat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat    
OutputFormat    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat
```

This Table should be transformed to have parquet and have the properties

```
Serde Library   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe 
InputFormat org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat   
OutputFormat    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat
```

The following Scala Spark code is executed:

```
val df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table")
df.write.format("parquet").mode("append").saveAsTable("table")
```

This results still in the unwanted the properties:

```
Serde Library   org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe  
InputFormat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat    
OutputFormat    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat
```

Hopefully somebody can help me

Comment: Are you appending to a table that already exists? If so, it will pull the properties of the existing table and use those.

Comment: I am not appending to the or a table that already exists. Basically my question is, how can I change the format of a table with HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat to a new table with the MapredParquetOutputFormat? Hope this clarified it a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not mix different file formats in the same table, nor can you change the file format of a table with data in it. (To be more precise, you can do these things, but neither Hive nor Spark will be able to read the data that is in a format that does not match the metadata.)

You should write the data to a new table, make sure that it matches your expectations, then rename or remove the old table and finally rename the new table to the old name. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table STORED AS PARQUET AS SELECT * FROM orig_table;
ALTER TABLE orig_table RENAME TO orig_table_backup;
ALTER TABLE new_table RENAME TO orig_table;
```

You can execute these SQL statements in a Hive session directly or from Spark using `spark.sql(...)` statements (one by one).

Comment: Could you provide an example?
Thanks at least for the answer :)